# Learn HTML5 CSS3 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

What is best way to learn these technologies which would enable me to understand all the 3 in a combined perspective rather than individually?

Comment: You learn all three individually. Everyone needs HTML, CSS enhances HTML with style, layout and animations. JavaScript enhances HTML/CSS with interactivity, IO and other black magic.

Comment: see : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/51319/is-there-a-canonical-book-on-creating-highly-interactive-websites-eg-flash-l

Answer (score 5):

Mozilla Developer Network has great resources; In my opinion it also has the best JS reference.

1. [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5)
2. [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS)
3. [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)

Comment: Well, you learn them individually and you use each one separately for a combined result.

Answer (score 2):

Learning style depends from person to person and in case you feel right in learning from books, I would suggest [Head First HTML5 programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449390544). The book has pretty decent examples explaining the potential of HTML incorporated with javascript. A little background of HTML and CSS is expected for no looking back into basic HTML and CSS rules. It's pretty easier and covers the most of basic requirements in todays web-apps.